# How can I search Giphy's GIF live with React.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, giphy, giphy-api

Based on the [official Giphy demo(CodeSandBox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/giphyreact-components-hbmcf?from-embed), I would like to create a live search function for Giphy GIFs.

And below is a demo of it.
[search demo（CodeSandBox）](https://codesandbox.io/s/giphyreact-components-8u8co?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
It holds the keyword as state and passes the keyword state to the search method of giphyFetch.
But the search results are not displayed.

Is there a problem with the code in the demo, or a solution to this problem?
Thank you.

### source code

```
const giphyFetch = new GiphyFetch("sXpGFDGZs0Dv1mmNFvYaGUvYwKX0PWIh");

function App() {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  const fetchGifs = (offset: number) =>
    giphyFetch.search(keyword, { offset, limit: 10 });

  return (
    <>
      <p>
        <img src="./logo.gif" width="200" alt="Powered by GIPHY" />
      </p>
      <p>
        input keyword
        <input type="text" onChange={e => setKeyword(e.target.value)} />
      </p>
      <h4>search result</h4>
      <Carousel fetchGifs={fetchGifs} gifHeight={200} gutter={6} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Carousal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@giphy/react-components#carousel) does the `fetchGifs` once upon mount. So you need to force re-mount upon your input `onChange`. You can do this by adding dynamic key

**Like this**

```js
...
     <>
      <p>
        <img src="./logo.gif" width="200" alt="Powered by GIPHY" />
      </p>
      <p>
        input keyword
        <input
          value={keyword}
          type="text"
          onChange={e => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
        />
      </p>
      <h4>search result</h4>
      <Carousel
        key={keyword}
        fetchGifs={() => fetchGifs(5)}
        gifHeight={200}
        gutter={6}
      />
    </>
...
```

Working [demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/giphyreact-components-issue-fix-2egtw?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working! I get a warning in the console, do you have any ideas on how to get around this warning? I looked into this warning, but I didn't understand the specific cause or solution.